# MySQL multiple tables full text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

On my current project I have something like the following tables.

```
Customer table          Task table
+----+----------------+ +----+--------------+-------------+
| id | name           | | id | description  | customer_id |
+----+----------------+ +----+--------------+-------------+
| 1  | teste client 1 | | 1  | do something | 1           |
+----+----------------+ +----+--------------+-------------+
| 2  | teste client 2 | | 2  | anything     | 2           |
+----+----------------+ +----+--------------+-------------+
```

And i want to search by task `description` and customer `name` using some user keywords.

```
select * 
from task t
inner join customer c on t.customer_id = c.id  
where match(t.description, c.name) 
against ('+test*+some*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Using the previous query i'm getting the following error `Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to MATCH`, i know that i can not use fields from diferent tables in the same match.

But how can i have the exact same results as the previous query using more that one match?

*(If someone have or knows a good article about this kind of problems, please let me know)*

**Updates**

Follow some exptected results for the provided query and data:

- when I search by `test` and `some`the result should be only `teste client 1`
- when I search by `test` and `client` the result should be `teste client 1` and `teste client 2`
- when I search by `any` the result should be `teste client 2`

You can check the expected result in the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a59a47/6) if for example we have only one table with both `name` and `description`.

Comment: where you able to find a solution to your problem or still looking for the proper query?

Comment: no i didn't find any solution for this problem.

Comment: I think your desired results table is mutually exclusive: when searching for `test and some` you match both tables, therefore only `test client 1` is returned. But when you search for `test and client` none of the customer_id matches in Tasks table but you still say both `teste client 1` and `teste client 2` should be returned. I think this is logically incorrect. Why would you omit the second table match in the second case and require it in the first case? Check the link to SQLFiddle with my tries in my answer.

Comment: Well yeah, I understand what you mean, but is there anyway to do that without having a separated table with both columns `name` and `description`? The problem of having the a separated table for search keywords, is that I have to maintain the info duplicated. You can check the update SQLFiddle i have create using yours.

Comment: there is no problem that FTS-ed columns are split among 2 tables. As you see from my fiddle we can effectivly combine them with `JOIN`.  The problem is that your condition whether to require only one table match or both is not definite. If you create a consitent matching requirements I think we will be able to create a query to select proper results even having columns split among 2 tables. We just need to know exactly when to require first table match only, second table match only, both tables match or at least one of 2 table match. BTW, I can't see your changes in Fiddle. Pls add a link.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED solution [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c79b3/45)

```
set @q = 'test* some*';

select * from 
(
    select
        c.id,
        c.name,
        match(c.name) against (@q IN BOOLEAN MODE) as t1_match,
        match(t.description) against (@q IN BOOLEAN MODE) as t2_match
    from task t
    inner join customer c on t.customer_id = c.id  
) as s
where s.t1_match > 0 OR s.t2_match > 0
```

Currently, I think your desired results logic is mutually exclusive. See my comment above.

Comment: The 1º option doesn't return the same result because `test` and `some` doesn't need to exist in both fields.
The 2º option i get exacly the same error `Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to MATCH`

Comment: @FxmL then change `AND` between `MATCH`-es to `OR` in the first query. See the updated answer.

Comment: if I use `AND` instead of `OR` I don't get the same as i get with only one `MATCH`

Comment: @FxmL no no, you should just try `OR`, orginally there was `AND` and I have changed it to `OR`.

Comment: I already try with both the result is not the same as using only one `match`, because if i do a query with two words `test` and `some`, if i use a `OR` all the rows with `test` and `some` will apear. When what i want is to get the rows with `test` and `some`.In the another hand if i use the `AND` and if the two word belong only to a table it will return zero rows.

Comment: @FxmL Your last comment is helpful, but it is still not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to get only those rows which have `test` and `some` in both tables at the same time? Could you pls add desired data output to the original ticket text?

Comment: thanks for your comment, i already add some more details about the expected results to the ticket.